# Context object is not updated after ajax called complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

Hi I am working on Dynamic web Project.

while file is selected from the jsp page. ajax is called.
and go to servlet.
and set context  attribute.

I am add sample code.
If any one has some Idea related to how to update context object..using ajax...

but context object is not updated.

> JSP page

```
<html>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(':file').change(function(){
                var fileObj = this.files[0];
                var fd = new FormData();    
                fd.append( 'file', fileObj);
                var form = $('#f1');
                alert(<%=context.getAttribute("uploadFile")%>); //false
                $.ajax({
                        url:form.attr('action'),
                        type:form.attr('method'),
                        data:fd,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        async:false,

                    }).done(function(data){
                        alert('ajax complete');
                        //context object is not updated after ajax called...
                        alert(<%=context.getAttribute("uploadFile")%>);  //false  
                        <%context = getServletContext();%>
                        alert(<%=context.getAttribute("uploadFile")%>);   //false

                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <form name="f1" id="f1" action="/test" method="post">
        <input type="file"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

> Servlet Code

```
if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
                try{
                    List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                    for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                        if(!item.isFormField()){
                            //File upload logic
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                context.setAttribute("uploadFile",true);    //set context attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

SerlvetContext is a Server side Object. Your JavaScript executes on the client and has no access to this. You need to have your Servlet send some kind of response (a plain String, JSON or XML) which will be available in the data object passed to  your JQuery function:

```
.done(function(data){
 alert(data);

});
```

Add some code to your Servlet to send the response:

```
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("File Uploaded");
  }
```